# Problemas al guardar en un array PHP

Tags: php, laravel, array

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de guardar una serie de números (ID'S) en un arreglo. Este es el código:

```
$subCategories = SubCategory::where('category_id', $id)->get();
        foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
            $prueba = [
                'prueba' => $subCategory->id
            ];               
        }  
        return $prueba;
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: resultado prueba]

Sin embargo, la variable **$subCategories** posee no uno, sino dos elementos como podrán ver a continuación:

[image: Como debería quedar]

Si ingreso el *return* dentro del foreach, ya no saldrá el número 6 sino el 2, así que no entiendo por qué al parecer está sobreescribiéndose y no agregando un elemento tras otro.
Gracias por leer y agradecería una respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución *mas simple* es emplear el método `pluck` indicando que genere un array con los valores de la columna que le pases como argumento, así te evitas generar código extra:

Tu query:

```
SubCategory::where('category_id', $id)->pluck('id');
```

Generando una salida:

```
[aquí todos los category_id recuperados]
```

De igual forma con el código actual alcanza con algo como esto para ir acumulando los valores recuperados:

```
.............
.............
$prueba[] = $subCategory->id
.............
```

Respecto a tu pregunta:

> ¿Estaría bien dejar la consulta $subCategories (ubicada en el código de mi pregunta) y agregar este otro query para ser enviados a través de compact hacia una vista?

Te comento que en realidad solo necesitas la query que ya tienes y posterior en la vista usar el método recomendado en este aporte para obtener por separado los identificadores, es decir:

- Así mandas la colección recuperada:

  ```
  $subcategory = SubCategory::where('category_id', $id)->get();
  ```
- Y así también en la vista empleado la misma variable obtienes por separado los id.

  ```
  $subcategory->pluck('id');
  ```

Recomiendo [repases esta fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Esta es la mejor solución si solo se requieren los ids. En el caso que se requieran más datos de la consulta, también es útil el helper Arr::pluck().

Comment: ¿Estaría bien dejar la consulta $subCategories (ubicada en el código de mi pregunta) y agregar este otro query para ser enviados a través de compact hacia una vista?

Comment: Revisa la edición a mi respuesta

Comment: Está bien, sin embargo, con los ids recuperados debo realizar otra consulta. Lo más óptimo es hacerlo desde el controlador, no?

Comment: Es opción desde el controlador, sin embargo la recomendación prevalece, haces una sola consulta y reutilizas la misma variable para fines distintos, en un momento obtienes todos los datos y en otro sacas los id (*como ejemplifico*) para colocarlos en otra query

Answer (score 1):

Porque efectivamente lo está igualando y no agregando, para agregar elementos al array usar array_push

```
$prueba = [];
foreach ($subCategories as  $subCategory) {
           array_push($prueba, $subCategory->id);               
        }
```

Si necesita que sea array asociativo, la llave debe ser diferente,

```
$prueba = [];
foreach ($subCategories as $key => $subCategory) {
          $arrTemp = [];
          $arrTemp = ['prueba'.$key => $subCategory->id];
           array_push($prueba, $arrTemp);               
        }
```